# MySQL Ignore is not working

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I am trying to prevent duplicates from occuring using the following query, but it doesnt seem to work. Please could you tell me what the problem is?

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Following SET `followingUserID` = '$accountIDToFollow', `followerUserID` = '$accountID'
```

Comment: Is (followingUserID, followerUserID) the primary key?

Comment: No, I am not using a primary key.

Comment: @Michael there is no error produced, it just isn't ignoring duplicates.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO 
    Following (`followingUserID`,`followerUserID`) 
VALUE 
   ('$accountIDToFollow','$accountID')
```

You were doing an UPDATE format before

If you are trying to do an update this is how it works

UPDATE `followingUserID`
SET
   `followingUserID` = '$accountIDToFollow',
WHERE
   `followerUserID` = '$accountID';

Of course you want to replace the were clause with the correct condition you want to do

Comment: edit--- I am getting the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: what are the values inside the 2  variables?

Comment: the variables are 5 and 6. my code is: INSERT IGNORE INTO Following (`followingUserID`,`followerUserID`) VALUES ('$accountIDToFollow','$accountID'

Comment: This will not work look at my code above, you only need one entry in the first parentheses `(followingUserID)`

Comment: ok, I pasted your query, and it entered the values in the same column on two different rows. Please see the image here:http://d.pr/jxY6

Comment: Oh i have to apologizze i have noticed the second column was follower instead of following. ok i updated my query copy the code above now

Comment: ok thanks, that works, but doesn't prevent duplication. I ran the script twice and it made two of the same rows instead of just one.

Comment: Maybe you should review your table schema. add unique index to those 2 columns

Comment: ok clear your table, with truncate, the run this query `ALTER TABLE Following ADD UNIQUE (followingUserID,followerUserID) ;`

Answer (score 1):

As per [MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) documentation,

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors
>   that occur while executing the INSERT
>   statement are treated as warnings
>   instead. For example, without IGNORE,
>   a row that duplicates an existing
>   UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in
>   the table causes a duplicate-key error
>   and the statement is aborted. With
>   IGNORE, the row still is not inserted,
>   but no error is issued.

It means, the IGNORE does not prevent any record duplicate. You will have to put Unique constraints on your given fields.

Comment: so instead of using IGNORE what should I use to detect duplicates so that something is called if there is a duplicate?